# Angular doesn't work in IE 8, can't create a custom element for my directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-directive

I built my application from scratch for the past few weeks.
I did it while implementing the instructions [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie).

I have to say that everything works great with any normal browser such as Mozilla or Chrome, and the Angular.js framework has been of much use to me.

The problem is that with IE8, everything seems to be broken, and the document.createElement 
DOM object throws an errro when I try to create an element for my custome directive(which I'm also using an 'x-' prefix for, as required by this lame excuse of a btowser).

A screen shot:
[image: Errros from the explorer development console]

app index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" xmlns:x-restrict="" xmlns:x-fileupload="" class="ng-app" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/form.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/meta.css">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
          <script src="js/json3.min.js"></script>
        <script>

        document.createElement('ng-include');
        document.createElement('ng-pluralize');
        document.createElement('ng-view');
        document.createElement('x-restrict');
        document.createElement('x-fileupload');
        // Optionally these for CSS
        document.createElement('ng:include');
        document.createElement('ng:pluralize');
        document.createElement('ng:view');
      </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <title>{{model.title}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="errorBar" ng-show="model.error.visible"><div class="errorBarContent">{{model.error.message}}</div></div>
  <div ng-include src="layout.menuSrc"></div>
    <div class="colmask threecol">
      <div class="colmid">
        <div class="colleft">
          <div class="col1">
            <ng-view></ng-view>
          </div>
          <div class="col2">
            <div ng-include src="layout.leftSideBarSrc"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col3">
            <div ng-include src="layout.rightSideBarSrc"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div> 
<!--<div id="mainFrame">
      </div> -->

      <div ng-include src="layout.footerSrc" id="footer"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- TODO: REMOVE THE CDN JQUERY AND REPLACE IT WITH ONE THAT IS LOCATED WITHIN THE PROJECT -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bluimp/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bluimp/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
     <script src="lib/bluimp/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
directive('x-restrict', function(authService){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        prioriry: 100000,
        scope: false,
        link: function(){
            // alert('ergo sum!');
        },
        compile:  function(element, attr, linker){
            var accessDenied = true;
            var user = authService.getUser();
            var attributes = attr.access.split(" ");
            for(var i in attributes){
                if(user.role == attributes[i]){
                    accessDenied = false;
                }
            }


            if(accessDenied){
                element.children().remove();
                element.remove();           
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should read this [article about using Angular with IE8 and earlier](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie).  There are some tricks you need to know about.  Whenever I target IE8 with Angular, I avoid writing element directives and stick with attribute directives instead.

Comment: Thanks for your time Brian.

I believe I have provided the same very link in my question.

Also all of my directive are of type restrict: 'A', as you can see in the code that I have posted.

Still doesn't work.

THanks again

Comment: Sorry about that.  I missed that.  One of the things it points out is that you need to set ng-app as an id: `id="ng-app"` (in addition to the attribute with the name of the module).  That is missing in your example.

Comment: it is my understanding that you can also use: class="ng-app", but I will definitely try and keep you posted

Comment: the page loads without errors but the directive still doesn't seem to work, maybe explorer doesn't.

maybe $compile doesn't work to well with IE8

Comment: Can you come up with a jsFiddle which demonstrates your problem?  I am targeting IE8 in a complex Angular site without trouble.  If I do run into issues, it tends to be something that needs to be polyfilled.  I'd ditch the `document.createElement` code completely and turn everything into attributes (including `ng-view`).

Comment: Yes I will do that.
I can get to in in an hour or two though.
Can you stay tuned?

Comment: Ok sir, I am certain of it now, there is some kind of a problem implementing this simple access directive for IE8:
http://plnkr.co/edit/gpe3Qj?p=preview

Comment: Obviously plunkr and IE8 are not friends:
here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BmQuY/3/

Comment: It works fine in IE10 emulation mode for IE8... I went to test it with my VM so I can run the real IE8 and I need to re-create my VM... I'll try to look at it when that is done.

Comment: Well, I am using the original IE8 on physical machine that has win7, that is dedicated for IE testing and other Microsoft stuff, and I get a weird error on the loading of the page, both on fiddle and plunker.

Thanks again!