# transclude not working (AngularJS 1.2 + Internet Explorer 8)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-ng-transclude

Running an AngularJS directive, with the transclude option, in the link function
the transclude() function will not return any Clone in IE8. It's working properly for IE9

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-app="fooApp">
    <foo>
        <span>(content to transclude)</span>
    </foo>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('fooApp', []);

app.directive('foo', [function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            console.log(transclude())
        }  
      }  
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/osOY27AUcRSO7QyfRsP9?p=preview

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

IE8 doesn't support the custom elements you need to use your directive as Attribute the make it working with IE8 compatible.

```
restrict: 'AE'
```

Same [**SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18593844/2435473) Here

Comment: is not a custom element issue. please refer to the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/osOY27AUcRSO7QyfRsP9?p=preview